# how to install a downloaded theme to magento?

Tags: magento, installation, themes

I am using **magento 1.8**. I downloaded a theme,

```
http://www.templatemela.com/new-style-magento-theme.html
```

Now I have the theme zip file. I searched over the internet but I couldn’t find any solution. I replaced the folders **app,** **js,** **skin** of magento root folder with the folders from theme folder. After that to activate the theme I open the admn dashboard I got an error,

```
The page isn't redirecting properly
```

Which is the correct way to install a new theme to magento?

Any one provide the step by step installation.

Comment: Check your DB configuration under app/etc/local.xml

Comment: @Slimshadddyyy Its correct. but its redirect me to a page http://localhost/magento/downloader/

Comment: Try to clear the folders var\cache and var\session. http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards%20/viewthread/204641/#t297908

Comment: @BalajiKandasamy cleared. but again it redirect me to the downloader page

Comment: Possibilities:

1) Clear webroot\var\cache and webroot\var\session folders
2) Does app/Mage.php file exist ?
3) Does app/etc/local.xml file in place and readable (have full permissions (777) )?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After you install the theme, go to System -> Configuration -> Design.

For the Themes section, set everything to modern, since that’s the name of the theme.

The theme will now be applied.

If you’re running the default install, you can make the front page look how the demo store on here does. For that you’ll need to update the CMS blocks, so go to CMS -> Manage Pages. Click on the Home Page.

You’ll be in the General Information section. Under Content, put the following:

{{block type="core/template" template="sample/home.phtml"}}

You can either comment out what’s already there, or just remove it completely.

Then you need to go to Custom Design and set the Layout to 1 column.

That’s it! Hope It will help you.

Answer (score 0):

there are 3 steps to install a downloaded Magento theme. I followed this tutorial: http://magentoexplorer.com/how-to-manually-install-a-downloaded-magento-theme and successfully to install ultimo theme downloaded from Themeforest

**Step 1:** Extract/unzip template file

**Step 2:** Upload theme to Magento root folder

**Step 3:** Activate your new Magento theme
[see the screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R6Myj.png)

Hope this helps